# Error on Xcode - Warning: all apps should include an armv7 architecture (current ARCHS = "")

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm constantly getting following error while building app.

The error is:
 Check dependencies

No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=armv7, VALID_ARCHS=arm6 arm7).
warning: all apps should include an armv7 architecture (current ARCHS = "").

How can I resolve this? I'm using Xcode 4.3.1.

Comment: How did you fix this?

Answer (score 48):

In your TARGET'S Build Settings look into "**Build Active Architecture Only**" set Debug to "NO" and Release to "NO"

Comment: Thanks! This worked great, but I wonder why/how. What did it actually do?

Answer (score 5):

This happened with my app when I had my iPhone connected to my Mac.
When I disconnect it and archive again selecting iOS Device it was OK.

Answer (score 3):

In your target's Build Settings there is a setting called "Architectures", which is probably empty. Add "armv7" and/or "armv6" to it.

Comment: Even better, put in $(ARCHS_STANDARD) so it gets updated automatically

Answer (score 1):

My problem was i wrote "armv7, armv7s", just remove the quote "," and it works ok.